# C - How to cycle a socket

Tags: c, sockets, printf, cycle, select-function

I have a program which prints the content of a file which I send:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *serverInfo;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

getaddrinfo(NULL, PUERTO, &hints, &serverInfo);
//socket para escuchar
int listenningSocket;
listenningSocket = socket(serverInfo->ai_family, serverInfo->ai_socktype, serverInfo->ai_protocol);
bind(listenningSocket,serverInfo->ai_addr, serverInfo->ai_addrlen);
freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);

listen(listenningSocket, BACKLOG);
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
int socketCliente = accept(listenningSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
char package[PACKAGESIZE];
int status = 1;

printf("\nCliente conectado. Esperando mensajes:\n");
printf("\nEl contenido del script es: \n");

while (status != 0) {
    status = recv(socketCliente, (void*) package, PACKAGESIZE, 0);
    if (status != 0) printf("%s", package);
}
close(socketCliente);
close(listenningSocket);
```

But I want this program listen for others things I want to print. So I need to cycle the socket, the listening of the socket. I understand I need the `select()` function, but I don't know how to use it for my code.

Comment: You need to call `accept()` in a loop. Each time a connection comes in, it will return a new descriptor for it.

Comment: When `recv` returns with an error, the value will be `-1`, and `package` will not be filled in. Also, think about what happens when the data received is not zero-terminated like a string should be.

Comment: Also, what makes you think that the 'package' buffer will always contain a nice null-terminated string?

Comment: the 'package' buffer will always contain a nice null-terminated string because all the scripts im sending are terminated like that. Here i only need to cycle the listenning and acept with select, but i dont know how to use it.

Comment: You are not sending scripts, you are sending a byte stream, and your 'status', if >0, tells you how many of those bytes have been received by the recv() call.  This can be between 1 and PACKAGESIZE and will not, in general, be null-terminated.

Comment: There is a complete lack of error checking in this code. Any of `socket(), bind(), listen(), accept(), connect(), send(),` and `recv()` can fail, mostly in ways which mean you should not proceed further. Try it again checking the result of every system call for -1 and if so calling `perror()` and exiting. You might get a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `select()` (or better, `epoll()`) in a loop, where you pass its `readfds` parameter an `fd_set` containing the listening socket descriptor and all connected client socket descriptors.  When `select()` exits, it will tell you which sockets have pending readable data on them.

If the listening socket has pending data to read, call `accept()` on it, and if successful then add the returned socket descriptor to a tracking list somewhere so that you can include it in subsequent calls to `select()`.

If any other sockets have pending data to read, call `recv()` on them and act on their data as needed.  If `recv()` returns -1 or 0 on any given socket, `close()` that socket descriptor and remove it from your tracking list so you omit it in subsequent calls to `select()`.

That being said, all of your socket calls are missing adequate error handling.  Any of them can fail, and you wouldn't know  This is especially important for `recv()` so you can properly detect and cleanup any disconnected/lost client connections.

Also, you are assuming that `recv()` always returns null-terminated strings, but that is simply not true.  A client may send a null-terminated string, but `recv()` is not guaranteed to read an entire null-terminated string in one read. You have to call `recv()` in a loop, buffering any received data in between, until you actually receive the null terminator, THEN proceed with processing the completed string.

Try something more like this (pseudo-code for you to fill in the implementation details of the client tracking list as desired):

```c
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *serverInfo;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PUERTO, &hints, &serverInfo) < 0) {
    // TODO: error handling...
    return -1;
}

//socket para escuchar
int listenningSocket = socket(serverInfo->ai_family, serverInfo->ai_socktype, serverInfo->ai_protocol);
if (listenningSocket < 0) {
    // TODO: error handling...
    freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);
    return -1;
}

if (bind(listenningSocket, serverInfo->ai_addr, serverInfo->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    // TODO: error handling...
    freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);
    close(listenningSocket);
    return -1;
}

freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);

if (listen(listenningSocket, BACKLOG) < 0) {
    // TODO: error handling...
    close(listenningSocket);
    return -1;
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrlen;
int socketCliente, maxfd, status;
char package[PACKAGESIZE];
char *str;
struct timeval timeout;

someList clients; // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...

while (!someStopCondition) { // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...

    fd_set rfd;
    FD_ZERO(&rfd);

    FD_SET(listenningSocket, &rfd);
    maxfd = listenningSocket;

    for (each fd in clients) { // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
        FD_SET(fd, &rfd);
        if (fd > maxfd) {
            maxfd = fd;
        }
    }

    // TODO: for you to decide on...
    timeout.tv_sec = ...;
    timeout.tv_usec = ...;

    status = select(maxfd + 1, &rds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (status < 0) {
        // TODO: error handling...
        break;
    }

    if (status == 0) {
        // TODO: do other things as needed...
        continue;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(listenningSocket, &rds)) {
        addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        socketCliente = accept(listenningSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
        if (socketCliente < 0) {
            // TODO: error handling...
        }
        else if (!addToList(&clients, socketCliente)) { // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
            // TODO: error handling...
            close(socketCliente);
        } else {
            printf("\nCliente conectado. Esperando mensajes:\n");
        }
    }

    for (each fd in clients) { // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &rfd)) {
            status = recv(fd, package, PACKAGESIZE, 0);
            if (status <= 0) {
                close(socketCliente);
                removeFromList(&clients, fd); // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
                continue;
            }

            // TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
            addToEndOfClientBuffer(fd, package, status);
            while ((str = getNullTerminatedStringFromClientBuffer(fd)) != NULL) {
                printf("\nEl contenido del script es: %s\n", str);
                removeFromFrontOfClientBuffer(fd, strlen(str)+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

// TODO: for you to decide the implementation of...
for (each fd in clients) {
    close(fd);
}
clearList(&clients);

close(listenningSocket);
```